# Why is constraint identifier not recorded?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, tableview

I set 4 constraint on my chid view controller:

```
        childController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        heightConstraint = childController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 800.0)
        leadingConstraint = childController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor)
        trailingConstraint = childController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
        topViewUpperConstraint = childController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: -44)
        topViewUpperConstraint.identifier = "topViewUpperConstraint"

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([heightConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, topViewUpperConstraint])
```

There is a table view in my child view controller, which I want it to be scrollable only when my child view controller's `topViewUpperContraint.constant` relative to the `bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor` of its `superView` is equal to -500.

I loop through the child view controller's constraint in a `UIScrollViewDelegate` method to find the constraint with the identifier `"topViewUpperConstraint"` like so:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let viewConstraints = view.constraints
    print("*** The number of constraint on the main view is: \(viewConstraints.count)")

    for constraint in viewConstraints{
        print("*** Constraint identifer is: \(constraint.identifier)")
        if constraint.identifier == "topViewUpperConstraint" {
            if constraint.constant == -500{
                tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
            } else {
                tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, there aren't any constraints with the identifier `"topViewUpperConstraint"` in the child view controller's set of constraint. Moreover, there are 13 constraint set on the main view, where as I only set 4. Can you please explain to me what I am missing here?

[image]

Comment: Why go looking for the constraint?  Just save a reference to it in a property when you create it

Comment: Yes, I thought of that. However, it is not very object orientedly ;) I really want to know why the constraint I'm looking for is not there, and why there are 13 constraints instead of the 4 I set. @Paulw11

Comment: The likely answer is you are looking through the wrong view's constraints, but personally I see nothing wrong from an OO point of view with just keeping the reference you need.

Comment: @Paulw11 you are right, I was looking at the wrong view. Subview constraints are added to the `constraints` property of the common superview. I looped through the superview's `constraints` property and found the constraint based on its `identifier`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you activate a constraint, it gets added to the *constraints* property of the common ancestor of the two views referenced in the constraint.  In your example, you are constraining the top of the view to the top of the bottomLayoutGuide, so the constraint will be added to their common ancestor in the view hierarchy which is likely the superview of your view.

There are 13 constraints because *Auto Layout* is setting up constraints for things you don't see and didn't add explicitly like the *bottomLayoutGuide*.

---

If you loop through `view.constraints` of `ViewController` without adding any constraints of your own

```
for constraint in view.constraints {
    print("Item1: \(constraint.firstItem), Item2: \(constraint.secondItem)")
}
```

you will see `8` constraints:

```
*** The number of constraint on the main view is: 8
Item1: <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fcedcd07e20; frame = (0 0; 0 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000025020>>, Item2: nil
Item1: <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fcedcd07e20; frame = (0 0; 0 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000025020>>, Item2: Optional(<UIView: 0x7fcedcd07a70; frame = (0 0; 414 736); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000024fc0>>)
Item1: <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fcedce05530; frame = (0 736; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000024ca0>>, Item2: nil
Item1: <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fcedce05530; frame = (0 736; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000024ca0>>, Item2: Optional(<UIView: 0x7fcedcd07a70; frame = (0 0; 414 736); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000024fc0>>)
Item1: <UIView: 0x7fcedcd07a70; frame = (0 0; 414 736); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000024fc0>>, Item2: nil
Item1: <UIView: 0x7fcedcd07a70; frame = (0 0; 414 736); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000024fc0>>, Item2: nil
Item1: <UIView: 0x7fcedcd07a70; frame = (0 0; 414 736); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000024fc0>>, Item2: nil
Item1: <UIView: 0x7fcedcd07a70; frame = (0 0; 414 736); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000024fc0>>, Item2: nil
```

which include 4 constraints for the `view` itself and 2 each for the *topLayoutGuide* and the *bottomLayoutGuide*.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Do also happen to know why I cannot find a particular constraint based on its identifier in the child view controller? @vacawama

Comment: You're not finding it because you're looking in the wrong place. The right place depends on how the view is added to the view hierarchy. I find it odd that you have a *child view controller*.  How is that view controller created and how is it added to your to your scroll view?

Comment: The child view controller is not added to the scroll view but rather to its parent view controller (which is just a `UIViewController`). The scroll view is contained within the child view controller. You can read more about container view controllers [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html). I looped through the common parent of the `child view controller` and the `bottom layout guide` and found the constraint by its `identifier`! Thanks @vacawama